# Dual space of $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

We know that:
If $V$ is a vector space, the collection of all linear functionals on $V$
forms a vector space, this space is the dual space of $V$. We denote
this space by $V^*$.

But I wanted to understand what it means $(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^* $ the dual projective space of  $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$.

$\mathbb{P}^{g-1}$ is not a vector space, so how could you understand its dual?

Comment: $(\Bbb P(V))^* = \Bbb P(V^*)$ by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathbb{P}^{g-1}=\mathbb{P}V$ for some vector space $V$ of dimension $g$. Then $(\mathbb{P}^{g-1})^*=(\mathbb{P}V)^*$.

An element of $(\mathbb{P}V)^*$ corresponds to a dimension one subspace of $V^*$ spanned by some linear functional $l$.

There is a one to one correspondence between dimension one subspace of $V^*$ and the corresponding vanishing set of $\mathbb{P}V$: 
$\{ [x]\in \mathbb{P}V\ |\ l(x)=0 \}$, which is a codimension one linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}V$. Therefore, you can regard element of $(\mathbb{P}V)^*$ as codimension one linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}V$.

Comment: thank you, @chan kifung !